# show multiple divs based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html file with certain number of divs (different every time) is generated aitomatically. For simplicity:

```
<div id="plate1">
  <p>plate 1 info</p>
</div>
<div id="plate2">
  <p>plate 2 info</p>
</div>
<div id="plate3">
  <p>plate 3 info</p>
</div>
<div id="plate2">
  <p>plate 2 additional info</p>
</div>
```

I am wondering about the possibility of dynamically filling a dropdown `<select multiple></select>` (based on unique block's ids):

[image]

And displaying only those divs, which are selected:

```
plate2 info
plate3 info
plate 2 additional info
```

Comment: Can you use Jquery ?

Comment: @Alexis , yes , sure

Comment: do you want to show div based on selection?

Comment: @UdhayTitus, yes, only those which are selected.

Comment: if you select first div, need to show first div content only

Comment: @UdhayTitus, excatly

Comment: @AlexIanevski i've update my answer like you want. If you prefer JQuery ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an object and assign a key to it as `id` of the element, set its value as `true`
- If another element having same `id` is iterated in `Array#filter`, it is filtered
- `Array#map` the filtered array and set `display` as `block` of the filtered elements
- Also create `option` elements having `selected` attribute
- Attach `change` event over `select` element
- If value of the `option` is `selected`, make `div` having `id` as `value` appear else `display : none`

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.plate');
var obj = {};
var filtered = [].filter.call(elems, function(el) {
  if (!obj[el.id]) {
    obj[el.id] = true;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
var selectOpt = filtered.map(function(el) {
  el.style.display = 'block';
  return '<option selected>' + el.id + '</option>';
});
select.innerHTML = selectOpt.join('');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  for (var i = 0, iLen = select.options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var opt = select.options[i];
    var val = opt.value || opt.text;
    if (opt.selected) {
      document.getElementById(val).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(val).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="plate1" class="plate">
  <p>plate 1 info</p>
</div>
<div id="plate2" class="plate">
  <p>plate 2 info</p>
</div>
<div id="plate3" class="plate">
  <p>plate 3 info</p>
</div>
<div id="plate2" class="plate">
  <p>plate 2 additional info</p>
</div>

<select multiple id='select'></select>
```

Comment: May all the values be initially selected?

Comment: I mean, whether this is posiible that all the options in the dropdown were initially selected, for now no options (no plates) are initially selected.

Comment: @AlexIanevski, You can, apply selected attribute over `option` and remove `display:none`. I have updated it for you..

Comment: Very nice answer. But instead of `document.getElementById(val).style.display = 'block';`  I have put  `var elms = document.querySelectorAll("[id="+val+"]");
        for(var j = 0; j < elms.length; j++)
          elms[j].style.display='block';`  and the same for else case.  So it works even if I have several identical IDs

Comment: @AlexIanevski – Yes.. That will work but I do consider the _fact_ —  [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

Just loop on all option who are `:selected` and show div depend of them `text()` or `val()`

```js
$("#myselect option").prop("selected",true);

$("#myselect").change(function(){
  $(".mydiv").hide();
  $("#myselect option:selected").each(function(){
    $("#mydiv"+$(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="myselect">
  <option value="1">div1</option>
  <option value="2">div2</option>
  <option value="3">div3</option>
  <option value="4">div4</option>
</select>

<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv1">First div</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv2">Second div</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv3">third div</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv4">Fourth div</div>
```